# How to pass the resultset of JDBC request over thread groups in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Here, i got a resultset from JDBC Request in setUp Thread Group, and i want to use it in another Thread Group as type of Resultset.

i've tried to use '__setProperty' in setUp thread Group, and use '__P' in the other thread group. but it's like to convert the ResultSet type to String.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define "Result variable name" in your JDBC Request sampler:

   [image]
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   props.put('result', vars.getObject('result'))
   ```
3. Once done you will be able to copy the resultset value back to [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the following thread group(s) as:

   ```
   vars.putObject('result', props.get('result'))
   ```

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on all these `vars`, `props` and other JMeter API shorthands